# Помогите понять смысл предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

О чем идет речь в следующем предложении:

"ОБ УТВЕРЖДЕНИИ ПЕРЕЧНЯ ДОМОВ, ПОДЛЕЖАЩИХ РАССЕЛЕНИЮ И СНОСУ ПОСЛЕ ПРИЗНАНИЯ АВАРИЙНЫМИ, НА 2017 - 2023 ГОДЫ".

Мнения разделились. Я думаю, что здесь речь идет о датах сноса и расселении домов, а знакомый, что о годах, когда нужно признавать дома аварийными. Все зависит от запятой.

Answer (score 1):

**Запятая стоит на месте, смысл вполне ясен.** И логика простая: нельзя проживать в домах, которые признали  аварийными.

К этому распоряжению дается приложение  ― список на **каждый год** тех домов, которые **будут обследованы** на предмет технического состояния строительных конструкций и инженерных систем. Если они (в этот год)  будут признаны аварийными, то их (в этом же году) будут сносить, так как проживание   в аварийных домах невозможно.

[ПЕРЕЧЕНЬ ДОМОВ, ПОДЛЕЖАЩИХ РАССЕЛЕНИЮ И СНОСУ...](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/446453298)

Answer (score 1):

Этот документ (http://docs.cntd.ru/document/446453298) как будто специально составлен так, чтобы "непосвященные" не смогли его понять. Если вам интересно не ЧТО НАПИСАНО, а ЧТО ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЛОСЬ, лучше спросить у авторов.